# How to target the next <div> element?

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on the hyperlink `<a>` it will open the content of the `<div>` that goes just after it. Right now I am adding ids to the `<a>` and the `<div>` to target them. But how I make this more efficient? My idea is to use a script which will search for the next `<div>`. This would avoid declaring ids.

```js
function open_content(y) {
    x=y.substr(-3,3)
    console.log(x);
    if (document.getElementById('content'+x).style.display=='none'){
        document.getElementById('click'+x).innerHTML="CLOSE";
        document.getElementById('content'+x).style.display='block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('click'+x).innerHTML="SHOW";
        document.getElementById('content'+x).style.display='none';
    }
}
```

```css
a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>CONTENT TITLE</h2>
<p><a id="click100" onClick="open_content(this.id)">SHOW</a></p>
<div id="content100" class="content" style="display:none;">
    <div> 
        <h3>Sub Title</h3>
        <p><a id="click101" onClick="open_content(this.id)">SHOW</a></p>
        <div id="content101" style="display:none;">
            <p>Place content here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **HTML**

```
<p><a id="click100" onClick="open_content(this.id)">SHOW</a></p>
<div id="content100" class="content" style="display:none;">
    ...
</div>
```

the link `<a id="click100" ...>` is **within** `<p>`, so that one need **first** the **parentElement**. And **then** the **nextElementSibling**:

```
var link = document.getElementById("click100");
var parentThenNext = link.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
```

So you can access the `<div id="content100">...</div>`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7wo98gsn/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function open_content(el) {
    // get a reference to the content div for the clicked "el"
    // parentNode used twice because of the <p> wrapping the <a>
    var targetDiv = el.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    if (targetDiv.style.display=='none'){
        el.innerHTML="CLOSE";
        targetDiv.style.display='block';
    } else {
        el.innerHTML="SHOW";
        targetDiv.style.display='none';
    }
}
```

then call with

```
<p><a onClick="open_content(this);">SHOW</a></p>
```

And yes, you can delete all the ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery parent() and siblings() method.
here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T3ouI8Pz4Q7misuxbU3f?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h2>CONTENT TITLE</h2>
<p><a  >SHOW</a></p>
<div  class="content" style="display:none;">
    <div> 
        <h3>Sub Title</h3>
        <p><a>SHOW</a></p>
        <div  style="display:none;">
            <p>Place content here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("a").click(function(){
      console.log($(this).parent().siblings("div"))
      $(this).parent().siblings("div").toggle();
    })
</script>

</body>
</html
```

>

Answer (score 0):

I’d try to pass `this` into `open_content()` instead of `this.id`. Having that I would be able to get link’s parentNode — the `<p>` — and then from there, just get the next element with `.nextElementSibling`. Something like this:

```
function open_content(toggleElement) {
    var contentElement = toggleElement.nextElementSibling;

    if (contentElement.style.display == 'none') {
        toggleElement.innerHTML = "CLOSE";
        contentElement.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        toggleElement.innerHTML = "SHOW";
        contentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Here is the updated HTML:

```
<h2>CONTENT TITLE</h2>
<p><a id="click100" onClick="open_content(this)">SHOW</a></p>
<div id="content100" class="content" style="display:none;">
    <div> 
        <h3>Sub Title</h3>
        <p><a id="click101" onClick="open_content(this)">SHOW</a></p>
        <div id="content101" style="display:none;">
            <p>Place content here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Good luck! 8-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your HTML structure, you'll have to get a reference of the parent of your anchor tag which is `<p>` in this case and then do a next sibling call on it.

`document.getElementById("anchor_id").parentNode.nextElementSibling;`